# How to put SSA in the Z3 solver

Tags: algorithm, z3, solver, z3py

I generated the SSA list for my code and now would love to solve the paths from `entry` to `exit`. Lets take this "simple" example of SSA expressions.

[image]

So then I would have a bunch of expressions:

```
z1>1
x1:=1
z1>2
x2:=2
y1:=x1+1
x3:=Φ(x1,x2)
z2:=x3-3
x4:=4
z3:=x4+7
```

However looking at the [Z3 examples](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) I cannot directly plug this into the solver, and instead have to generate symbols for them, moreover it seems assignments are not allowed seperately (like `x4:=4`).

So I wonder if there is any *easy* way to convert SSAs like above such that I can directly put them in python Z3 solver?

Comment: SSA = [Static Single Assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)?

Comment: What is meant by "solving" a path?

Comment: @AxelKemper, aah yeah SSA = Static Single Assignment (should've mentioned that). More generally I actually mean how to translate SSA code in something solvable by Z3. For example, `x3:=Φ(x1,x2)` and `x4:=4` do not seem to be "valid" input for Z3

Comment: This is surely doable by asserting equalities for each new variable. In fact, SSA transformation is what's used first so you can translate it to SMTLib/z3 etc. Simply create new variables and assert equality. For phi-nodes, you can use uninterpreted functions. What have you tried, and what didn't work? Stack-overflow works the best if you show what you attempted.

Comment: Give https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie a try: Its language is a mix of first-order logic and imperative code, from which SMT code is generated. Writing the latter by hand would definitely be instructive and insightful, but also cumbersome, for any non-trivial example.